# Where is 'catalog_product_save_before' dispatched?

Tags: event-observer

I'm struggling to find the dispatch event for the`catalog_product_save_before`.

I've done a find of my entire project on the following search term: `catalog_product_save_before`. It's only found in 3rd party modules.

I'm looking to utilise this event, but first I'd like to inspect the code around the dispatcher to ensure I'm doing it in the correct area.

Events are dispatched as follows:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_save_before', $data_array);
// Assuming in this case that $data_array is a qualified array
```

This appears nowhere in the core, which is puzzling. Is it perhaps defined in a different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event is dispatched in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave`.
It is this line:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
```

The product model class is a child class of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and the `_eventPrefix` member is `catalog_product` for the product model.

Comment: just give us all a chance....I was about to hit post :)

Comment: @DavidManners. Sorry. Most probably this is my last answer for today. I'm going home. Didn't recover yet from mm14ro :).

Comment: I suspected as much, but I had no idea where to even begin a search! Thanks for this.