# Event for adding a new product

Tags: event-observer

What is the event name for when a new product is added?

I have looked here:

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-event-observer-with-save-before-and-save-after/

But catalog_product_save_before doesn't seem to be on any Magento event list for 1.7, 1.8 or 1.9.

Comment: Ah found it:

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36056/where-is-catalog-product-save-before-dispatched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that `catalog_product_save_before` works on every magento version.

You don't find it because there is no explicit call to `Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_save_before', ....)`.
The event is dispatched in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave()` through the line

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
```

the product model extends `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and the original `_beforeSave` method is called. In the product case `$this->_eventPrefix` has the value `catalog_product`. Check the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` to see for yourself.

So you actually get

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
```